# Recorrer DataTable y eliminar las columnas que el valor de la fila sean igual a 0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagrid

Tengo que recorrer un `DataTable` y borrar las columnas que tengan fila = 0, y estoy intentando recorrer las Columnas pero no puedo entrar al dato de la fila, como lo puedo resolver?

Esta es la tabla que tengo que recorrer, y verificar si hay algún campo igual a 0.. Si lo hay lo quiero eliminar

[image: Esta es la tabla que tengo que recorrer]

Y este es el código:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult ObtengoStock(string sku)
    {
        DataTable datos = Metodos.StockPorSKU(sku);


        foreach (var row in datos.Columns)
        {
            if (row.ToString() == "0") {
               // datos.Rows.Remove(row);
            }
        }
        return Json(datos);
    }
```

Al hacer esto siempre me recorre lo que seria "c01, c02, c03", y yo lo que quiero recorrer es la fila de abajo, que tiene 1 o 0

Comment: Tu pregunta es un poco confusa, en el título dices eliminar filas, y en el detalle dices eliminar las columnas... Aclara mejor que lo que deseas lograr.

Comment: @J.Rodríguez si hasta yo me confundi, lo que yo quiero eliminar son las Columnas, que el dato de su fila sea igual a 0, por ej, "c02 tiene 0" -> eliminar esa columna

Comment: Ok pero ,qué pasaría si tienes mas de una fila, y en la _fila cero(0)_ la columna `C01 = 0` y en la _fila uno (1)_, en la misma columna `C01 = 1` o cualquier otro valor??? , la primera condición eliminaría la columna aunque en la siguiente fila no tenga un valor cero....

Comment: @J.Rodríguez Por ejemplo, en la imagen que subi, "c01" tiene 1, entonces lo dejo... al pasar a 'c02' y ver que tiene 0, lo remuevo , y asi que siga por los demas.. No se si me estoy explicando bien

Comment: @J.Rodríguez osea, a lo que yo quiero llegar es que me devuelva una tabla solamente con las columnas que tengan 1

Comment: No me has entendido, tu `DataGridView` solo tendrá una sola **fila** siempre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
     for (int i = dt.Columns.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
     {
          if (row[dt.Columns[i]].ToString() == "0")
          {
              dt.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
          }
     }
}
```

Usa el `foreach` para recorrer el `DataGridView` fila por fila, y después el `for` para ir recorriendo todas las columnas, y así quitas las columnas que tengan valor 0

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo era eso lo que buscaba, no me daba cuenta de hacer dos iteraciones

Comment: dudo que funcione, ya que no dice si 0 o 1 es un string o no, puede ser un número

Comment: si se puede, si el valor es un entero, entonces solo tiene que convertir a entero el row[dt.Columns[i]].ToString(), ademas con el ToString(), ya estas convirtiendo el calor de la celda en string

Comment: Funciona perfecto

Answer (score 0):

```
        foreach (var row in datos.Row){
        if (row["c01"]==0){//do something
}........
    }
```

Tienes un lío entre filas y columnas, tienes que ir elemento por elemento. Es decir, fijado una fila, miras en cada columna (identificas el campo así) si el valor es el deseado